# Https сертификат

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

Так прошу очень помогите я хотел SSL бесплатный сертификат установить сайт есть freessl что то такое. Так я скачал их файл в ФТП открыл папку туда файлы т.д сертификат/код все сделал. .htaccess сделал:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://firesafety.az/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Так написано было в private_html все файлы я сделал все окей работает.Я захотел вернуть http стандарт. В cpanel нажал использовать стандарт сертификат там htaccess удалил из private_html удалил файлы и хочу зайти на сайт не как не могу прошу помогите от вас

Comment: https://www.reg.ru/support/ssl-sertifikaty/ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata/ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata-v-cpanel  - например так...

Answer (score 0):

Для http не нужен стандарт. сертификат. Вообще не нужен никакой. Просто файлы сайта должны лежать там где положено и всё.

Comment: файлы в public_html и все настройки я обратно сделал всеравно пишет угроза безопасности и кидает на https

Comment: Однако меня не кидает -- проверил. Теперь и вы проверьте что вы пишете в адресной строке. Надо написать так: http://firesafety.az

Comment: Я щас еще раз проверю

Comment: Вот в cpanel сделал все кидает в https htaccess тоже удалил я

Comment: у меня даже локальный сервер есть там проверяю да все туда тоже зайти не могу в сайт кидает

Comment: Вам надо свою систему проверить. Я на ваш сайт захожу нормально с самого начала.